# Refresh ListBox control during a loop

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listbox

Using ASP.NET and VB.NET code behind, I have the following code:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim I As Integer = 0
    For I = 0 To 10
        ListBox1.Items.Add(I)
        ListBox1.DataBind()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300)
    Next
End Sub
```

The intended output of the code is to update the listbox1 control at each iteration, but what really happens is it updates the listbox1 control after the entire loop finishes..

Is there a way to update the listbox1 control as its intended by the code logic?

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the `ListBox` inside `UpdatePanel` and trigger the `Button1_Click` event as  as Async; Something like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="pnlUpdate">
      <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
      </ContentTemplate>
      <Triggers>
          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
      </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I tried your suggestion and I still get the update after the loop finishes..

Comment: This can't update the Items collection of ListBox1 in each iteration, this only allow you to update the control/item when `click` event is handled. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I see.. is there a way to update the items collection of listbox1 in each iteration?

Answer (score 0):

This should work accordingly:

```
Dim I As Integer = 0
For I = 0 To 10
   ListBox1.Items.Add(I)
Next
```

If you debug then you'll see with each iteration an item is added to Items of ListBox1 control but the effect only be visible if the page/form is loaded.

Comment: This doesn't work on ASP, I still get the updates after the loop finishes.

Comment: You can't see the updated data in `ListBox1` if the page is not reloaded. Thanks for your time.

Comment: But that is what I need, to see the updates real-time, not after the page reloads

Comment: Okay, but you only be able to see that in debug time, to see please follow: Put a `breakpoint` at line `ListBox1.Items.Add(I)` and after executing this line hover your mouse pointer on `Items` in (ListBox1.Items.Add(I)), a pop-up will show and then expand that popup, and then expand `Non-Public members` and then expand `listItems` and then you'll see some indexes like [0] [1] etc. the count will be total number of items in the listbox items collection. Are you happy by seeing these data? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I know that, and its not what I need.. Thank you for your Answer